# Laravel Google tag Manager

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, google-tag-manager

Good day to all.
I connected the tag manager to the site, but I want to be sure that it is on all pages.
This is an online [home appliance store](https://grandeconom.com/).
I want to understand the Laravel principle, how can I find all the pages?
Help me figure out the code
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. For a quick check, I normally use http://www.gachecker.com/ Very useful, it not only indicates absent libraries, it also indicates double libraries. Pretty useful.
2. You can implement basic pageview tracking through GTM and in a few days see if there are missing pages in Analytics report.
3. You could use your sitemap or access log (grouped by page path) to check it manually or with a site crawling tool.
4. Finally, sure, you can go through Laravel's page templates and make sure GTM is referenced in each. I'm not an expert in PHP frameworks though.

If you want to see Laravel-only solution, you should ask your question with no reference to GTM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers